# Shell independent way of setting environment variable

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, tcsh

I need to make a script which can modify an environment variable of the calling shell. To allow the script to modify the environment variable I'm using `source <script>` and I want both bash and tcsh to be able to use the same script.

I'm hitting the fact that tcsh and bash have different `if` syntax so I can't even switch between the two inside the script. What is the best way to handle setting the environment variable?

Comment: Detect the shell outside the script you're sourcing, and use two different scripts for POSIX shells and tcsh :) Writing a script that works in both POSIX sh and tcsh would probably be rather painful (but maybe not actually impossible, since both support `||` and `&&`...)

Comment: That's what I afraid of. Thanks for letting me know

Comment: Question:  why are you using two different shell languages?  It might be a better long term strategy just to stick to one.

Comment: I strongly concur with cdarke -- much saner to do the usual thing and have `yourscript.csh` and `yourscript.bash` for something intended to be sourced, and make it the user's fault to choose appropriately. csh syntax is [full of pitfalls](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt), and writing anything substantial in it is going to require making compromises best avoided.

Answer (score 1):

I hate to write an answer that does little more than expand on the comment made by [@Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5951320/ash) to the original question. But I felt it important to note that you need to consider not just POSIX 1003 shells like bash and classic shells like csh/tcsh. You also need to consider modern alternatives like [fish](http://fishshell.com/) which is not compatible with either of those shells.

As @Ash noted the solution is to use "bridge" code for each of the invoking shells which maps the information into the syntax appropriate for the invoking shell.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, [you got me](https://xkcd.com/356/). I did some experimentation, and you might actually be able to do this with one script. (**Update:** I way overcomplicated the original, here's a much better solution that also works in zsh.)

What you're trying to create is a bash/tcsh *polyglot* (we'll assume for now that you don't want to support any other shells). I'll put the actual polyglot here, then some explanation and caveats afterwards:

```
if ( : != : ) then
    echo "In a POSIX shell or zsh or ksh"
else
    echo "In tcsh"
    alias fi :
endif
fi
```

The first line is really the interesting bit in this polyglot.

In POSIX sh, it creates a subshell to run the command `:` with two arguments, `==` and `:`. `:` always returns true, so the first branch of the if-statement is executed. (Usually a semicolon is used after the condition in an if-statement, but in fact a close-paren works too, since both are *control operators*, which can be used to end a *simple command* – the condition in an if-statement is really a *list*, but that degenerates to a *simple command*, going by the Bash manual.)

In tcsh, it compares the string `:` with the string `:` – since they are equal, and we were testing for inequality, it executes the second branch.

The last line of the second (tcsh) branch just ensures that that tcsh won't complain that the final `fi` isn't a command. There's no need for a similar alias in the first branch, because the `endif` is still in the second branch of the if-statement as far as a POSIX shell is concerned.

---

With regard to caveats, you're somewhat limited in what you can actually do in the POSIX shell section: for example, you can't define any functions with the POSIX syntax (`foo() {...}`), since tcsh will complain about the parentheses, although the Bash syntax (`function foo {...}`) works. I assume there are similar limitations in the tcsh section.

This polyglot also doesn't work in fish, though it does work in zsh. (That's why the condition is `: != :` rather than something like `: == ''` – in zsh, `==` expands to the path to the command `=`, which doesn't exist.) It also appears to work in ksh (though at this point it's turning into less of a polyglot, more of a "is this shell csh" program...)

Comment: aside: `function foo { ... }` dates back to pre-POSIX ksh; it's the hybrid `function foo() { ... }` that's a bashism and compatible with neither POSIX nor ksh.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh wow, that's really cool – I had no idea. It sounds like some other features people often call bashisms, like `[[`, are actually from ksh too!